# Optimizar show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, animación

**¿Como puedo optimizar este código?** Necesito algo simple, pero para conseguir el resultado que quería he tenido que usar demasiado código.

**Basicamente...**

**1-** Tengo un input de texto donde el usuario puede introducir el nombre del producto a buscar en la tienda.

**2-** Por defecto todos los productos son visibles, al introducir una letra... `p` por ejemplo quiero de desaparezcan todos los productos (`.product-wrap`) que no contengan dicha letra en su nombre (`.title`).

**3-** El paso anterior esta logrado con exito... Pero no quiero que desaparezcan del DOM de repente si no con un efecto de `fade`... Tanto al aparecer, como al desaparecer. En caso de que borre la `p` deben aparecer todos de nuevo con `fade`.

**4-** Si no hay ningun producto que contenga dicho texto... abajo veis que muestro u oculto una alerta (`#no-results-alert`). Como puedo hacer para que esto funcione con fade... Ya que `:visible` no me vale...

```js
    // Search Filter Button
    $("#search").on("input", function() {

        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".product-wrap").filter(function() {
            
            //Esto funciona... Pero sin animacion, apareciendo y desap. bruscamente
            //$(this).toggle($(this).find(".title").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

            //Esto funciona correctamente... Pero necesito optimizar esto al maximo...
            if($(this).find(".title").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){
                $(this).addClass('fadeIn')

                if($(this).hasClass('fadeOut')){
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut');
                }
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('fadeOut')

                if($(this).hasClass('fadeIn')){
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
                }
            }

        });

        // Al hacer fadeIn y fadeOut... No puedo detectar que no quede ningun elemento...
        if($(".product-wrap:visible").length == 0){
            $("#no-results-alert").show();
        }else{
            $("#no-results-alert").hide();
        }

      });
```

```css
.product-wrap{
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                    <input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>

<div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 1</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 2</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 3</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 4</h3>

  </div>
  
 </div>
```

> PROBLEMAS

- :visible no funciona, ya que fade juega con la opacidad...
- Si buscamos el 4, este no se mueve a la posicion del 1... se queda en
  la suya... esto no lo quiero... Un hide, show al final de la animacion serviria creo...
- Optimizacion, necesaria. Uso demasiados condicionales para lo que
  creo que hace falta.

Comment: Buenas puedes editar tu codigo y crearlo en un snipet para poder trastear con el? un saludo

Comment: Ok, mas o menos ahi lo he puesto. Simplemente si hay alguna forma mas optima, y el tema de :visible que no funciona. Por lo que no se muestra nunca el mensaje de no hay productos...

Comment: Voy a echarle un vistazo y te digo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con esto:

```
.hide("fade",1000);
```

Al hacer un `hide`, en lugar de un `fadeIn/Out`, el elemento desaparece, por lo tanto los otros elementos ocupan su lugar.

**EDICION**
Te adjunto lo que se he podido optimizar. La busqueda no se puede hacer nada mas.

```
// Search Filter Button
    $("#search").on("input", function() {

        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".product-wrap").filter(function() {
            if($(this).find(".title").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){
                    $(this).show('fade');
            }else{
                $(this).hide('fade');
            }
        });

        // Al hacer fadeIn y fadeOut... No puedo detectar que no quede ningun elemento...
        if($(".product-wrap:visible").length == 0){
            $("#no-results-alert").show();
        }else{
            $("#no-results-alert").hide();
        }

      });
```

Comment: el toggleClass logicamente no funciona, pues se ejecuta cada vez que el usuario introduce o borra un caracter... por lo que añade y quita la clase correspondiente constantemente.

Comment: en esta parte del codigo -- ( if($(this).hasClass('fadeOut')){ $(this).removeClass('fadeOut');}) -- que esta dentro del 'filter' viene a ser algo como: "si 'this' tiene esta clase, entonces quitala". no? Pues entonces es toogleClass de toda vida. Saludos

Comment: El toggleClass si la tiene la quita, si no la tiene la añade... Por cada caracter que el usuario escriba o borre... Se añade y quita la clase dependiendo de si existe o no.

Comment: Creo que no nos entendemos, despues de comer te dare un snippet para que lo veas.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a ir editando según vaya resolviendo

1º Para que te vaya actualizando la posicion debes añadir

```
$(this).css("display", "block")
```

y

```
$(this).css("display", "none")
```

Te voy actualizando el codigo por aquí:

```js
 // Search Filter Button
    $("#search").on("input", function() {

        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".product-wrap").filter(function() {
            
            //Esto funciona... Pero sin animacion, apareciendo y desap. bruscamente
            //$(this).toggle($(this).find(".title").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

            //Esto funciona correctamente... Pero necesito optimizar esto al maximo...
            if($(this).find(".title").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){
                $(this).addClass('fadeIn')
        $(this).css("display", "block")
                if($(this).hasClass('fadeOut')){
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeOut');
                }
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('fadeOut')
        $(this).css("display", "none")
                if($(this).hasClass('fadeIn')){
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
                }
            }

        });
 // Al hacer fadeIn y fadeOut... No puedo detectar que no quede ningun elemento...

    // Ejecuta la funcion solo si el elemento esta visible
    if( $('.product-wrap').is(":visible") ){
     $('#no-results-alert').css("visibility","hidden")
  }else{
     $('#no-results-alert').css("visibility","visible")
    }
})
```

```css
.product-wrap{
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#no-results-alert{
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                    <input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>

<div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 1</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 2</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 3</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="product-wrap animated fadeIn col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 my-2">

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title">Producto 4</h3>

  </div>
  
  <div >

    <!--CODE CODE AND MORE CODE..--->
    <h3 class="title" id="no-results-alert" style="visibi">No Existen Productos</h3>

  </div>
  
 </div>
```

AQUI TE DEJO EL SNIPPET CON TODO

Comment: el display none se hace instantaneo en el fadeOut... de todas formas esto supone añadir mas codigo... cuando lo que busco es eliminar si es posible.

Comment: pero para que se realice esto: Si buscamos el 4, este no se mueve a la posicion del 1... se queda en la suya... esto no lo quiero... Un hide, show al final de la animacion serviria creo..necesitas usar el display block y display none porque el fade lo que haces es un visibility hidden y un visibility visible por lo tanto no los muestra pero siguen ocupando su lugar